# Superagent .attach() file or buffer data is empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, superagent

I ran into this issue where superagent does not properly attach a file or a buffer into the request and the reason I mentioned empty is due to the form data looking like :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryy6T3XReWRFT1KfFm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"


------WebKitFormBoundaryy6T3XReWRFT1KfFm--
```

there isnt any information on the file and it comes up as empty `media:`

The code I'm using is simple:

```
.post(`${API_ROOT}${url}`)
        .withCredentials()
        .attach('media', body.media, 'filename.jpg')
```

Where `body.media` is:

```
asBuffer(file, callback) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
asBuffer(file, ((b) => {
    body.media = b;
}));
```

or

```
body.media = new FormData();
body.media.append('file', inputFile, inputFileName);
```

or along with after `asBuffer`

```
Buffer.from(body.media, 'base64');
```

where `inputFile` is of type `File`.
I have also played around with `attach` and omitted the filename when the `body.media` was not of type `Buffer`.

I don't believe there is a problem on my end as using `.send(body.media)` actually attaches the file to the request formdata and I can see it in the back-end server. Only the `.attach()` function does not work properly and I need it to as I also need to send fields.

The only workaround I found at this moment was this:

```
const mediaFile = body.media;
delete body.media;
.post(...)
    .withCredentials()
    .query(body)
    .send(mediaFile)
```

and I dont actually feel comfortable getting a huge url just to be able to send a file along with my fields.
I've seen some issues like this posted already, but none had seem to have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L571

shows that superagent has its own `FormData` variable to which it appends attached files to - meaning the use of `FormData` of my own is redundant and therefore causes nesting which results in an empty payload.

So just passing an `inputFile` of type `File` to `.attach()` solves the problem.

Furthermore for the fields I had a dozen of them to which solution was:

`.field('fieldName', JSON.stringify(body))`

And in the back-end server simply: `JSON.parse(req.body.fieldName)` to get the request payload in JSON format.